# Petición a instagram funciona en postman pero no en curl php

Tags: php, curl, instagram

estaba haciendo una prueba para atacar la url de instagram

https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/direct_v2/get_presence/

que te devuelve, entre otras cosas, la hora de conexión de tus contactos.

La petición la he cogido a partir del navegador, y en postman per funciona correctamente.

Pero cuando exporto del postman con la opción de Code>PHP - cURL, que ya te genera el código php para ejuctarlo directamente, en este caso recibo un error 5xx Server Error

Este es el código que me genera postman (con algunos elementos quitados)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/direct_v2/get_presence/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    ": authority: i.instagram.com",
    ": method: GET",
    ": path: /api/v1/direct_v2/get_presence/",
    ": scheme: https",
    "accept:  */*",
    "accept-encoding:  gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language:  es-ES,es;q=0.9",
    "cache-control:  no-cache",
    "cookie:  ig_did=xxxxxxxxxxxx; mid=xxxxxxxxxxx ig_nrcb=1; csrftoken=xxxxxxxxxx; ds_user_id=xxxxxxxx; sessionid=xxxxxxxxxxx; shbid=xxxxxxxx; shbts=xxxxxxxxxxxx; rur=PRN; urlgen=\"{\\\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\\": 15704}:1kmgwd:nzxuUo4OeF-ptzrxCQarP_P8Kxw\"; csrftoken=u4BATwsJAt1Ief9qqtK71fJYH5Uh3hz0; ds_user_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; urlgen=\"{\\\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\\": 15704}:1kmxoP:D3wqR1fE4NKUdo9bFzy0ziqpBdE\"",
    "origin:  https://www.instagram.com",
    "pragma:  no-cache",
    "referer:  https://www.instagram.com/",
    "sec-fetch-dest:  empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode:  cors",
    "sec-fetch-site:  same-site",
    "user-agent:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "x-ig-app-id:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "x-ig-www-claim:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Por si sirve, aquí os paso la respuesta con las cabeceras que recibo:
Por si sirve, aquí paso también la cabecera de la respuesta, con la respuesta completa:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 10 Dec 2020 08:44:44 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 105

<html>
<head>
<title>5xx Server Error</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>5xx Server Error</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores del servidor, y podrían ocurrir por algo tan simple como una línea no terminada con `;`, o cualquier carácter fuera de sitio en el código. Revisa el log de errores.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu aportación.
En principio no és eso, ya que la petición se realiza correctamente. El error 5XX no lo devuelve mi servidor, si no el de instagram.

Comment: Te lo dice claro: `5xx Server Error`, literalmente, *Server Error*  significa **Error en el Servidor**. Debes por tanto revisar tu código PHP, el error está ahí. Convendría que revises el log de errores en tu servidor.

Comment: Aunque también se aprecia un error 400, que puede estar causando a su vez el error en el servidor.  [Puedes leer más aquí sobre las causas del error 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). En la documentación de la API de Instagram supongo que te explican cómo escribir de un modo correcto peticiones cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he dado con el problema.
El problema viene por los dos puntos que se definen al principio de los 4 primeros campos. cambiando a esto, ya ha funcionado:

```
'authority: i.instagram.com',
'method: GET',
'path: /api/v1/direct_v2/get_presence/',
'scheme: https',
```

Gracias por vuestros consejos.